# tikz overlay inside beamer onslide still occupies spaces?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Adam Optimizer}
Initialize ...

Parameter $\beta_1$ is usually 0.9.

Calculate momentum 
$$ a=b $$

Calculate velocity

$$ b=c $$

\onslide*<2>{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node {hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\onslide<3->
Then we have ...

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

From slide 1 to slide 2, the text shifts up a bit. How to fix this?

[image]

Is the tikzpicture with overlay option still somehow occupy space?

I also tried to change `\onslide*<2>` to `\onslide<2>`, then the text doesn't shift, but the space between `b=c` and `Then we have ...` is enlarged.

Comment: Add a `%` right after `\onslide*<2>{` and another one after `\end{tikzpicture}` with no spaces before the `%`.

Comment: @abcdefg Your comments are useful, but for me I have to add % on the next line of `}` and after `\onslide<3->`. Then it's fixed.